# Object goes in the opposite direction of the curve

Tags: curve-modifier

I made a fence object and tried to follow the curve.
But the object doesn't follow.

Objects and curves are the same. Pivot point, Position, Rotation, Size...
What are the possible causes?
[image]

[image]

Comment: I thought that the -X direction might be the problem, so I set it in the +X direction and it worked. Is this the only solution?

Comment: did you try st the factor x to +1 ?

Comment: Probably switch curve direction in edit mode (Segment > Switch Direction) or share your file. In general I would say you should set Array to positive X and Curve modifier to follow -X.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!

Comment: 1) Set array modifier factor X to natural number 1.
2) I switched the direction of the curve. This worked. There may be no other way. Thank you for your help♡

Comment: You should probably post your last comment as an actual answer

Comment: oh OK! thank you for teaching me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set *Array* modifier *Factor X* to natural number 1.
2. I switched the direction of the curve.

[image]